# Django- Display columns depending on chosen filter in ModelAdmin (list_display)

Tags: python, django, django-modeladmin

I'm trying to show different columns(in list_display) depending on chosen filter.

Here is my code:

```
# Filter:
class FilterNameFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = ('FilterName')
    parameter_name = 'FilterName'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('xxx', _('xxx 1')),
            ('yyy', _('yyy 2')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'xxx':
            return queryset.filter(c__isnull=False)
        if self.value() == 'yyy':
            return queryset.filter(d__isnull=False)


# Model:
class pricelist_admin(ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('EAN_id', 'Vendor', 'Description', 'DynamicColumn', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
    list_filter = ('Vandor_id__Name', FilterNameFilter)
    search_fields = ('EAN_id__Description', 'EAN_id__EAN')

    #Dynamic column:
    def DynamicColumn(self, obj):
        if  # ... Here is my code for showing different columns,
            # it works fine for other loop's examples, but I don't know 
            # how to integrate it with "FilterNameFilter" to return desired columns:
            return obj.e
        else:
            return obj.EAN.Description
```

Any ideas? Help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As a work around I created proxy model:

```
class SomeClass(pricelist):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

with separate ModelAdmin where I can play with my columns:

```
class pricelist2_admin(ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('EAN_id', 'Vendor', 'Description', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a')
    list_filter = ('Vandor_id__Name', FilterNameFilter)
    search_fields = ('EAN_id__Description', 'EAN_id__EAN')
```

so I guess this would do for now...